# how to install bourbon?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, bourbon

I installed bourbon successfully but I can't see any folder in my project why ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not creating a `Bourbon` project by installing a `gem`. You are just installing the `Bourbon` application. Read about [what is `gem`](http://guides.rubygems.org/what-is-a-gem/).

To create a `Bourbon` project (ensure that your `gem`s are inside your `PATH`) run:

```
bourbon install
```

This will create a `Bourbon` project inside the current folder. Also, see all the [docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/wiki/Command-Line-Interface) on the `Bourbon`'s CLI.